# Does a Readied Action or Delayed Turn count as an Opportunity Action or Immediate Action?

Tags: dnd-4e, actions

Do Readied Actions or Delayed Turns count against your usage limits for Opportunity Actions or Immediate Actions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trigger for a readied action is an Immediate Action.  If you have used your Immediate action prior to the readied trigger then you are out of luck.

> **Immediate Reaction:** A readied action is an immediate reaction. It takes place after your enemy completes the action that triggers it.

Delay<sup>**[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=327)**</sup> is a **NO ACTION**.  You must delay your entire turn.  This does not provide you with an extra opportunity or immediate action.

1. Regular turn
2. Delay (Opportunity Action(OA) and Immediate Actions do **not** reset)
3. Coming back into Initiative, start turn (now OA and Immediate's reset)

Comment: This seems to make sense, but could you provide supporting rules citations?